# Stub a call to Rails.application.config_for with Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a method with the following line:

```rb
permissions = Rails.application.config_for(:admin_auth)
```

It reads the file `config/admin_auth.yml` and returns a Hash that I use later in the the same method.

The problem is that in order to test this method I need to give different values to `permissions` but I can not find the way to stub the `Rails.application.config_for` call.

I tried:

```rb
allow(Rails::Application).to receive(:config_for) { { admin: 'super_admin' } }
```

But I get an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think stubbing configs is not a good idea, since it is likely that rails env would be loaded before you actually get to anything in your test. You could consider the following solutions for this case:

1.Separate permissions into a method and stub it

```
# code
def permissions
  Rails.application.config_for(:admin_auth)
end

# test
allow(your_object).to receive(:permissions).and_return({ admin: 'super_admin' })
```

2.Setup your file according to [Flexible Rails environment config](http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/flexible-rails-environment-configuration/)

Comment: That looks like a good solution. The problem is that my object is a helper module called Admins::AuthHelper and `allow(Admins::AuthHelper).to receive(:permissions).and_return({ admin: 'super_admin' })` does not seem to work.

Comment: If it's a view helper method, you could try `allow(helper).to receive(:permissions).and_return({ admin: 'super_admin' })`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
allow_any_instance_of(Rails::Applcation).to ...
```

or

```
allow(Rails.application).to ...
```